# My code does not correctly compare strings of different length

Tags: java, string, compare

I am supposed to write a compare method that essentially does what the compareTo method does. I have written the code but it does not compare strings of different length. 
This is my code:

```
public static int compare(String a, String b)
{
    int result = 0;
    a = a.toLowerCase();
    b = b.toLowerCase();
    //program assumes strings are equal

    for (int i = 0; i<a.length() && i<a.length(); i++) {
        int c = a.charAt(i);
        int d = b.charAt(i);

        if (c < d){
            result = -1;
            break;
        }
        if (a.length() > b.length()) {
            result = -1;
            break;
        }
        if (a.length() < b.length()) {
            result = +1;
            break;
        }

        if (c > d) {
            result = 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

I have done an if loop comparing 2 strings of different lengths but, yet, the program ignores that.
Im trying to understand my mistake so please don't just give me the answer without explaining for I will not learn anything.
Thanks, in advance.

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger? If you're using some kind of an IDE it should come with a suitable interface for it. Try to step through the program and pay special attention to all the conditions you've written and how they affect the code. Try to compare strings "Ala lubi kota" "Ala ma kota".

Comment: For learning purpose its OK. But all otherwise use String.equals() method. In software engineering there is a saying - "Don't reinvent the wheel"

Comment: im using DrJava. i dont know if it has one but, yeah, I will do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you want to make sure, when comparing character by character, that `i` is less than both `a`'s length and `b`'s length.  Right now, you're comparing `i` to `a'`s length twice.

Try:

```
//                                *
for (int i = 0; i<a.length() && i<b.length(); i++){
```

Second, you only want to compare lengths if you have compared each character equal until one of them has ended.  Place the length comparisons after the `for` loop.

Third, `"mars"` comes before `"marshall"`, so if `a`'s length is less than `b`'s length, then it compares less also.

```
// After the for loop ends:
if(a.length() > b.length()){
     result = 1;
     break;   }
if(a.length() < b.length()){
     result = -1;
     break;
```

Comment: Nice!! Thanks alot mate!! I understood completely with what you said and I fixed my code with your help of course :)